# Throw a die three times, and get maximum number of different sums.

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, recreational-mathematics, contest-math, open-problem

The [IBM Ponder This](http://domino.research.ibm.com/Comm/wwwr_ponder.nsf/Challenges/July2013.html) problem for July 2013 throws an 8 sided die 3 times, and can get 120 possible different positive integer sums.  If all the faces have positive integer sides, what is the lowest possible value for the highest face?  For an $n$ sided die, the maximal number of different sums is a [tetrahedral number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number).  Here are my best results for d3-d7.

d3: 1, 2, 5  -- 10 sums
d4: 1, 2, 8, 12  -- 20 sums
d5: 1, 2, 16, 19, 24  -- 35 sums
d6: 1, 3, 12, 27, 43, 46   -- 56 sums
d7: 1, 2, 8, 51, 60, 79, 83  -- 84 sums

The d8 is the contest problem, so don't post that answer.  I'm curious about d9, d10, and so on.  I used a sieve method, but it doesn't scale up well. There is a related question in polynomials

```
Total[Sign[CoefficientList[Expand[(1 + x^2 + x^8 + x^12)^3 ], x]]]
```

The above 4 term binary polynomial has 20 coefficients in its cube, which is maximal.

Is there an elegant way to find d9, d10, d11, d12, and so on?

Comment: Best so far for d9     

[1, 4, 6, 33, 85, 160, 188, 205, 226]   
[1, 7, 21, 36, 112, 139, 187, 204, 226]

Answer (score 1):

George Sicherman (of [Sicherman dice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sicherman_dice) fame) sent me his best results for d9 and d10

1 2 19 93 133 162 200 204 210

1 4 5 14 47 156 216 270 332 347

These involved a large search, no nice method for finding these is known yet.

Comment: Are these 'best' as in the search was exhaustive, or as in best so far?

Comment: I found this slightly better solution for d9: 1 2 18 27 128 139 186 205 209, so I guess that answers my own question.